# Как запустить такой проект в idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Стыдно, да, но не могу разобраться,так как за Джаву взялся только только. Разбираю пример, да не могу запустить.Как это делается в IDEA? Все стоит последних версий если что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После компиляции ничего не отображается, если что,никаки GUI и т.д.

Comment: Конечно никаких ГУИ. Потому что судя по всему это jsp проект. Для этого его нужно скомпилировать, собрать war файл и задеплоить на каком-нибудь АС или хотя бы в контейнере сервлетов Tomcat. После чего в браузере можно будет найти свое ГУИ

Comment: Спасибо.........